# How to send number of HTTP requests/second for 1 hour with every request body is having one unique id in it in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

My Requirement is :

To send 50 request/second for 1 hour continuously with below payload :

```
    {
     "car": 
      {
        "id": "car-${CarId}",
        "type": "four wheeler"
      },
      "associates": 
        [
          {
            "wheels": 
            {
               "id": "wheelfor${CarId}",
               "type": "wheel"
            }
          },
           {
             "steering": 
             {
               "id": "steeringfor${CarId}",
              "type": "steering"
             }
           }
        ]
      }
```

Here , I want to change value of ${CarId} in every request and it should be unique , too.

can anyone please help me in this ?

Comment: Could you please add what steps you already tried to achieve results. It is very open-ended question.

Comment: Hi @AshutoshNigam , I have followed below steps : 

I have added thread group with below configuration : 

1) CSV Dataset config (I have stored 50 unique ids in one csv)
2) Added one HTTPS Request with above given payload
3) Added view results in tree and table as listeners
4) Set Thread Count to 50 and executed it. 

But the issue is how i can generate payload with 50 unique ids every second and hit the service for more time let say 30 min or 1 hour.

Thanking you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can make this `${CarId}` random/unique by adding [User Parameters](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/quick-guide-jmeter-preprocessors) preprocessor and declaring `CarId` variable there using i.e. [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) or [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) or [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) functions as the parameter value

   [image]
2. In order to run your requests for 1 hour configure [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) as follows:

   [image]

   the number of threads of `300` is for reference only, you may need to adjust it up or down
3. To limit requests to 50 per second add [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) and configure it to send 3000 requests per minute (50 requests/second * 60 seconds)

   [image]

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for the detailed solution. I got the desired output now.

Again thanks much :)